# Printing variable value in Psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, printf, psychtoolbox

I'm looking for a way to print the value of a variable to the screen in Psychtoolbox (Matlab). I'm looking for something like `fprintf`: eg. `fprintf('%s%d\n','Your score: ', score);`

I'm guessing that `DrawFormattedText()` is the function I'm looking for, but can someone advise how to add a variable that isn't a part of the string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format data into a `string` and then pass that `string` to the [`DrawFormattedText`](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/DrawFormattedText) function from the [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) like this:

```
score = rand;    % Random score value.
DrawFormattedText(win, sprintf('Your score: %d\n', score));
```